# Lotus Notes - Find similar Fields (SELECTION)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I'm trying to make a view that will display possible duplicate documents. So a selection formula that compares one field over all the documents and only diplays those that are similar.

I ahve been playing arond with @Like and @Matches, but can't seem to get it to work. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference from a view selection formula to other documents. The selection formula works only for the current document and decides if this document shall be visible in view.

You can write an agent which compares all documents with all the other documents and sets a flag (=item/field) to a document if it has similar fields with the other documents. You can then select all those flagged documents in your view.

Comment: I feared that was the case - thanks Knut I will look into creating an agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view where the first (sorted) column contains the field you want to check against. Then use @SetViewInfo to filter the view to only show documents matching a specific value.